# Is it possible to nest flexsliders? (with manual navigation?)

Tags: views, panels

I have use case where I need to nest a flexslider into another flexslider; I'm not having much success and was hoping someone might be able to provide some insight. It should look something like this:

[image]

Basically, I have panelized nodes which each contain a flexslider pane generated by Views using the flexslider formatter. These panelized nodes with flexsliders also need to appear as slides in another views-generated flexslider on a landing page.

Unfortunately, the landing page doesn't seem to be processed correctly by flexslider's JS; `<li>` elements are getting rendered underneath the flexslider element, navigation controls the wrong slideshows, etc. I have I think I'm having a hard time finding the correct selectors to use for each flexslider. I see I can add an element id to the flexsliders in Views and I have set up unique presets for the inner node flexslider and outer landing page flexslider, but using a string like `#innerflexslider > li` in the advanced settings doesn't seem to work.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Thanks! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks"? What do you see in browser's JS console?

Comment: My bad, topic has been updated, I was very confused when I first posted this. No errors in the console. I think I've narrowed it down to an issue of finding the right selectors to use in settings.